# MySQL row to column from subquery

Tags: mysql, sql

I need help with how to write SQL query to output data in format that I want.

I have this query that returns below output,

```
select d.date, d.meal, sum(swipe) 
from (
  select date, meal, card_id, count(card_id) as swipe 
  from history where date >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 2 DAY) 
group by card_id, meal, date
) as d 
group by d.date, d.meal
```

Current Output:

```
+------------+-----------+------------+
|    Date    |   Meal    | sum(swipe) |
+------------+-----------+------------+
| 2015-10-27 | Breakfast |        138 |
| 2015-10-27 | Dinner    |        205 |
| 2015-10-27 | Lunch     |        247 |
| 2015-10-26 | Breakfast |        137 |
| 2015-10-26 | Dinner    |        190 |
| 2015-10-26 | Lunch     |        231 |
+------------+-----------+------------+
```

Is it possible to query from above output to return something like this:

```
+------------+-----------+-------+--------+
|    Date    | Breakfast | Lunch | Dinner |
+------------+-----------+-------+--------+
| 2015-10-26 |       137 |   231 |    190 |
| 2015-10-27 |       138 |   247 |    205 |
+------------+-----------+-------+--------+
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You need a conditional aggregate to pivot:

```
select d.date, 
   sum(case when meal = 'Breakfast' then swipe else 0 end) as Breakfast,
   sum(case when meal = 'Lunch' then swipe else 0 end) as Lunch,
   sum(case when meal = 'Dinner' then swipe else 0 end) as Dinner
from (
  select date, meal, card_id, count(card_id) as swipe 
  from history where date >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 2 DAY) 
group by card_id, meal, date
) as d 
group by d.date
```

Btw, this query can probably be simplified to:

```
select d.date, 
   sum(case when meal = 'Breakfast' then 1 else 0 end) as Breakfast,
   sum(case when meal = 'Lunch' then 1 else 0 end) as Lunch,
   sum(case when meal = 'Dinner' then 1 else 0 end) as Dinner
from history 
where date >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 2 DAY) 
group by d.datle
```

Comment: Or even simplified a little further in MySQL

Comment: @Strawberry:  `sum(meal = 'Breakfast')` is shorter but proprietary. I prefer the verbose syntax as it's Standard SQL and supported by every DBMS.